# Why I cannot initialize group definition from jar file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to create bean from jar file from our company to retrieve data from database.
I added

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>common.context</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to my web.xml,
then there are some errors happened

Here is stacktrace:

```
Nov 01, 2013 2:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group   definition. Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml], factory key [common.context]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common.context' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [edu.ucsd.act.student2.common.email.JavaEmailSender] for bean with name 'javaEmailSender' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/edu/ucsd/act/student2/common/email/JavaEmailSender.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:386)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:536)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:376)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common.context' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [edu.ucsd.act.student2.common.email.JavaEmailSender] for bean with name 'javaEmailSender' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/edu/ucsd/act/student2/common/email/JavaEmailSender.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381)
... 19 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [edu.ucsd.act.student2.common.email.JavaEmailSender] for bean with name 'javaEmailSender' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/edu/ucsd/act/student2/common/email/JavaEmailSender.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
... 32 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [edu.ucsd.act.student2.common.email.JavaEmailSender] for bean with name 'javaEmailSender' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/lib/student2-common.jar!/edu/ucsd/act/student2/common/email/JavaEmailSender.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1265)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 34 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
... 47 more


Nov 01, 2013 2:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 01, 2013 2:42:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/studentMyEnrollment] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I thought this was because I am missing a jar file contain org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl
this particular file is in springframework-context-support jar file and I do have it and build the path of it
Now I have no idea why is this happening when I start tomcat server.
Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>...</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>common.context</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- spring context -->
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    

<listener>
<listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>...</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>...</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: is the same library there when you launch the app (runtime) ?

Comment: yes, I put jar file in tomcat/lib and build path to it @JigarJoshi

Comment: why do you put your jar in tomcat/lib and not in the WEB-INF/lib of your application ,

Comment: because in our company server, all of our application are using same lib, and my application have to work with other applications, so this is the folder structure that works in my company, I am still trying to understand that. @FredericClose

Comment: web app specific libraries should be visible just to that app, typically path is WEB-INF/lib/

Comment: I tried to put particular jar file in WEB-INF/lib, but nothing changes @JigarJoshi